# Recalculate field with JS

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to recalculate one field in Odoo based on another field so for example my model is following:

```
class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    margin = fields.Float()
    netto_price = fields.Float()
```

So based on netto_price i would like to calculate margin. Now i added js file to `/static/src/js/products.js` and in openerp.py i added `'js': ['static/src/js/products.js'],`

Than i wrote following js just to try if its working or not

```
openerp.product_mycustom = function(instance) {

    var QWeb = openerp.web.qweb;
    _t = instance.web._t;

    instance.web.FormView.include({
        load_form: function(data) {
            var self = this;
            this.$el.find('#netto_price').on('change', function() {
                alert( this.value );
            });
        },
    });
};
```

And no success. Am i doing something wrong

Comment: what exactly is the problem with using the `onchange` decorator?

Comment: Odoo has a way to recalculate fields in real time by using computed fields (see https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html). Why would you prefer to use JS?

Comment: Thanks didnt know about onChange!